# CKEditor losing characters when typing

Tags: ckeditor

At our hospital we are using a medical application "TrakCare" which is written by InterSystems. The product makes use of the CKEditor JavaScript editor which they embed in many of the "TrakCare" web pages (the whole product is web based). It has been reported by many medical staff that when typing into CKEditor Rich Text controls, some entered characters are being lost.

It was very hard to reproduce because it only seemed to happen when 
you typed fairly quickly and none of us could type both accurately and consistently enough for us to be certain it wasn’t our mistake. So I wrote a standalone VBscript to do the typing for us. This script used SendKeys to enter a line of text at different entry speeds (starting at 5cps and going up to 30cps).

We found that when the test script entered text at exactly 10cps and the focus was in the CKEditor control, we lost about 30% of all entered characters into the CKEditor control.
When the script entered text faster (11cps or higher) or slower (9cps or lower) there was no loss of input.
When focus was elsewhere (e.g. Winword, notepad, any normal text field in IE) typing was fine at any speed with no loss of characters.

We've tried this from the following OS and browser combinations:

- Windows 7 x64 clean PC. IE11. 8GB RAM. i5 CPU.
- Windows 8.1 x64 domain joined PC. IE11. 8GB RAM. i5 CPU.
- Windows Server 2012 R2 domain joined server. IE11. 12 core Xeon CPU. 24GB RAM.

Results are the same on all platforms.

We haven't tested in other browsers because the TrakCare medical application only works fully in IE11 because it makes use of various IE add-ins for which there are no Chrome or Firefox equivalents.

We are not making any progress with Intersystems support so we thought we'd ask the CKEditor community if they have any ideas. Is there anything about this control which you can think of which might cause the results we are seeing?

Comment: What version of CKEditor are you using?

Comment: How can I tell? Remember we didn't purchase or install CKEditor - it comes with a larger product and we only know it's CKEditor because a) InterSystems told us and b) It looks just like CKEditor from the screenshots I've looked at (of CKEditor). Sorry that's not too helpful.

Comment: Is there a hotkey or something we can view in the HTML source which would tell us the version of CKEditor?